# How to use JWT Validation within Azure Function Merthod?

Tags: c#, azure, authentication, jwt

I have some logic ported from an API which I need to be able use within an Azure function

I need to do validation on JWT tokens

My function will have specific roles that a user must have to be able to get a response from the function

I have got this in my function startup

```
        var tokenOptions = configuration.GetSection("JwtIssuerOptions")
            .Get<TokenConfiguration>();
        
        var tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            // The signing key must match!
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            IssuerSigningKey = tokenOptions.SecurityKey,
            // Validate the JWT Issuer (iss) claim
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidIssuer = tokenOptions.Issuer,
            // Validate the JWT Audience (aud) claim
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidAudience = tokenOptions.Audience,
            // Validate the token expiry
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            // If you want to allow a certain amount of clock drift, set that here:
            ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
        };
        
        services.Configure<IdentityConfiguration>(configuration.GetSection("IdentityConfiguration"));
        services.AddScoped<CustomJwtBearerEvents>();

        services
            .AddAuthentication(o =>
            {
                o.DefaultForbidScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                o.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.TokenValidationParameters = tokenValidationParameters;
                options.EventsType = typeof(CustomJwtBearerEvents);
            });
```

In an API context I would be able to have this taken care of by middleware packages and [Authorize(Roles="role1")]

However, that doesnt appear to be supported within Azure functions

How can I achieve the same thing within Azure?

I have a request that already has a token on it ready for checking

Paul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below links might help. Azure filters are used as attribute in azure.

1. https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/wiki/Function-Filters
2. https://markheath.net/post/secure-azure-functions-app-easy-auth-adb2c

Comment: Thanks a lot I got it to work with function attributes

Comment: @Paul can you explain a little how you solved this?